# Issue with backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, process, progress-bar

could anybody knows any alternatives to progressbar? Inmy project im using progressbar..I would like to change it to something like a rotating gif image which indicates the processing or someother labels which prevents the user from interacting to the program.I tried to implement the gif image by using background worker but its hanging may be coz of huge file transfer process.. So im searching for someother alternative like a label which will prevent the user to interact with the program and shows the progress in % . Could anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

You should be doing the long running file transfer in the background, not the animated gif.

Answer (score 3):

From your description it sounds like you're doing things the wrong way round. It is the long download that should run in the BackgroundWorker, not the progress bar / picture. The progress updates need to run in the main UI thread. Use the ReportProgress method to tell the UI when it should update. The BackgroundWorker implementation automatically calls Invoke for you, so that the UI updates will run on the correct thread.